# Passing arguments to Method References

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Given this method:

```
private static Integer getVal(Integer a, Integer b){
   return a + b;
}
```

which can be called as a lambda:

```
a -> getVal(1, 2)
```

Is there anyway of turning this into a method reference, something like:

```
Class::getVal
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are passing constants to the method call, you can create another method that calls the original method:

```
private static Integer getVal (Integer a) {
    return getVal(1,2);
}
```

then you can use method reference for the second method.

i.e. you can change

```
a -> getVal(1, 2)
```

to

```
ClassName::getVal
```

That said, it doesn't make much sense.

P.S., it's not clear what's the purpose of `a` in your lambda expression, since you are ignoring it.

In general you can pass a method reference of a given method if it matches the signature of the single method of the required functional interface.

Example:

```
public static Integer apply (BinaryOperator<Integer> op, Integer a, Integer b)
{
    return op.apply(a,b);
}
```

Now you can call:

```
apply(ClassName::getVal)
```

with your original method.

Comment: Thanks. That's really the question - how to pass the integer values to the lambda, like:  (val1, val2) -> getVal(val1, val2)

Comment: @user1052610 It depends where you are passing your method reference to. If you are passing it to a method that requires a functional interface having a method with 2 arguments, you can pass your original method.

Comment: It's being passed to the second argument of Map.computeIfAbsent(). So what I'd like is map.computeIfAbsent("xxx", Class:getVal)

Comment: @user1052610 The second argument of `computeIfAbsent()` takes a `Function<? super K, ? extends V>`, so it requires a method with a single argument, not two.

Comment: What if the first argument was an object wrapper which contains two values. Would it be possible to pass that way?

Comment: @user1052610 Please edit your question with the relevant code of your concrete case if you want a concrete answer. Otherwise it's hard to answer.

Comment: @user1052610 that sort of looks like `deconstruction pattern` to me, but it's only going to be available in jdk-10 (probably) and only for switch statements, check project amber for more details....

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example.

```
interface Operator {
    int operate(int a, int b);
}

class Calc {
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // using method reference
        int result = operate(1, 2, Calc::add);
        // using lambda
        int result = operate(1, 2, (a, b) -> Calc.add(a, b));
    }

    static int operate(int a, int b, Operator operator) {
        return operator.operate(a, b);
    }
}
```

You need a functional interface to use method reference (In this example `Operator`). And you also need a method which accepts an instance of the functional interface as its parermater (In this example `operate(int a, int b, Operator operator`).

**UPDATE**

If you need an object wrapper, just change the `operate` method to

```
static int operate(ObjectWrapper wrapper, Operator operator) {
    return operator.operate(wrapper.getA(), wrapper.getB());
}
```

And then call the `operate` method:

```
int result = operate(wrapper, Calc::add);
```

Answer (score 1):

getVal() will only be usable as a method reference, in places where a functional interface of an applicable type is expected, such as [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) or [IntBinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html), or a custom functional interface (as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47988743/1649029) of zhh)

Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer result1 = calculate(1, 2, Second::getVal);
        Integer result2 = calculateAsInt(1, 2, Second::getVal);
    }

    private static Integer getVal(Integer a, Integer b){
        return a + b;
    }

    private static Integer calculate(Integer a, Integer b, BinaryOperator<Integer> operator) {
        return operator.apply(a, b);
    }

    private static int calculateAsInt(int a, Integer b, IntBinaryOperator operator) {
        return operator.applyAsInt(a, b);
    }
```